# Is it possible matrix nxn matrix has no basis of null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The Problem ask about basis of null space of nxn matrix 
but when I solved it I found it has trivial solution that mean every variable equal 0 and linearly independence.
But the problem ask basis for null space  and vector 0 can't be basis 
Can I use standard basis as basis for null space ?  or  this matrix has no basis for null space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you found that $\ker(A)=\{0\}$, then $\varnothing$ is a basis of $\ker(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the matrix is square, if the matrix corresponds to a linear transformation that has full rank (so the image of the map is $n$-dimensional), then the null space has to be zero dimensional. Then the null space must have a trivial (empty) basis.